# Our iOS application rejection clarification

Tags: ios, encryption, appstore-approval

Our app was recently rejected by apple for 2 reasons,

- App Store Review Guidlines section 11.13
- iOS Developer Program License Agreement section 2.3

App Store Review Guidlines section 11.13 states:

> Apps that link to external mechanisms for account creation, purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, such as a “buy" button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected
>   Program License Agreement

- Does this mean we can not have an account creation section in the app?
- Does this apply to sub links on web pages. So for example, if we have a button that opens safari on the iPad on the https://www.dropbox.com/ page. Would that be against the terms?
- If our terms of use agreement has websites on it where you can register and or buy things once registered, would that violate the terms?

iOS Developer Program License Agreement section 2.3 states:

> You certify that (i) none of the Licensed Applications contains, uses or supports any data encryption or cryptographic functions; or (ii) in the event that any Licensed Application contains, uses or supports any such data encryption or cryptographic functionality, You will, upon request, provide Apple with a PDF copy of Your Encryption Registration Number (ERN), or export classification ruling (CCATS) issued by the United States Commerce Department, Bureau of Industry and Security and PDF copies of appropriate authorizations from other countries that mandate import authorizations for that Licensed Application, as required.

We are based in South Africa (if thats even applicable), We also definitely need encryption, if we obtain a CCATS from the United States Commerce Department, Bureau of Industry and Security and send it along with out next submission of of our application, will it be sufficient.
The app uses `CCCrypt` for AES encryption and `SecKeyEncrypt` for public key encryption.

Please let me know if you need any further information.

**EDIT**

So after a huge explanation with apple, me repeating myself over and over saying there is no links what so ever to anything on the app. I also gave them a document from the United States Commerce Department, Bureau of Industry and Security for the encryption. Apple even sent me screenshots where they say there are links but there are no links on the screenshots...
Anyway after all that they said:

> Thank you for your response. It would be appropriate to remove any account creation functionality from the app.

Seems like they just want me to remove the register section for no reason at all.
But since there is nothing i can do about it. I will just have to have an iPad app with no registration section.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app store approval processes

Comment: if so, where should i ask this question?

Comment: You should ask Apple https://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/

Comment: I have tried asking apple there responses are not useful, there approval staff are not the best.

Comment: Are you using any third party API like paypal etc. for purchasing anything in your app ?

Comment: Yes, to buy credits. But the credits are bought on the website and there are no links to the website on the ios application.

Comment: That means your app has Register/Buy button that takes the user to a website where a payment option can be found.This button as well as the link on the page should be removed.
If you want to use payement you can user In-APP purchase provided by Apple itself.

Comment: There is not links to the website at all, the registration is done on the iPad itself. We refuse to give apple commission. The purchasing of credits are optional, there is also no way to purchase the credits on the ipad without manually going to the website with a browser.

Comment: If you are doing all the payment procedure on iPad itself even though its optional then you have to use In-App API. If you try to byPass IAP you app will surely reject.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55904/discussion-between-akshay-aher-and-nicolas-tyler).

Answer (score 3):

**When to use Third party Payment Solutions:**

-You can use third party API (e.g. Paypal) if the user is buying real goods like shirt, shoes etc.

**When to use In-APP Purchase:**

-If user is buying digital goods, like music,ebooks then the app must use Apple's In-App payment technology.

You can get more info on following link:

[In App Purchase Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf)

Comment: As iv said before, we do not have links to the website, there is no buy buttons on the app.

Comment: @NicolasTyler: So a user that went and downloaded your app would never be told "go here to buy stuff"?  How do they know the site even exists?

Comment: They really dont have too.